# JWPlayer error codes list

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, jwplayer

I want to use [onError](http://sdk.jwplayer.com/ios/docs/reference/Protocols/JWPlayerDelegate.html#//api/name/onError:) for accurate error handling. JWPlayer documentation gives a list of errors https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403682-troubleshooting-your-setup. But these errors don't have codes with them. Does anyone have a concise list of possible error codes generated by JWPlayer upon failure?

Answer (score 0):

I reach out to JWPLayer regarding this concern since we struggled with the same issues not being able to handle errors correctly. The response was not really satisfying but understandable:

> We don’t have a formal list of errors since errors can happen on many levels (for example, errors with our SDK initialization, errors during playback due to the video file itself, errors related to retrieving the video file from your server, etc.)
>   I would also like to point out that the error delegates methods that I shared with you have error parameters that are of type NSError. This means that you can localize the error and get more information that way.
>   However, I would of course be happy to decipher any error that may arise.
>   -Daniel

What I ended up was listening to the three delegates `onError`, `onSetupError` and `onAdError`. This helps debugging. If it is an option you can react appropriately there. If you want a first list you should look at apples documentation of the AVPlayer: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/av_foundation_error_constants/error_codes). This is the underlying player.